# Are my unacknowledged kafka messages dropped due to network latency?

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, latency, librdkafka

I have `rdkafka` producer written the following way, where `localhost:9095` is tunneled to a digital ocean server in Germany with a kafka broker, whereas i, the localhost, am in New York.

I am noticing that at around ~150 miliseconds of `thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(150))` the last few of my messages stop being acknowledged by the callback (messages 8 and 9 for example),as if they didn't arrive. I know they did because i see the Kafka topic.

I'm wondering if my guess is correct that it is *solely* the latency between NY and Germany that dictates how long the broker takes to respond or if there is some config `max.response.wait.ms` setting i can set for acknowledgements to arrive sooner.

Of course if i increase the sleep time to ~200ms and higher i can see each message logged loud and clear. If i decrease sleep to 50ms the producer drops before any messages are sent  and they never arrive to the topic... right?

```rust
 let producer :ThreadedProducer< ProducerLogger> =   ClientConfig::new()
        .set("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9095")
        .create_with_context(ProducerLogger{})
        .expect("Failed to create producer");

        for i in 1..10{
            let mut data = [0u8; 8];
            rand::thread_rng().fill_bytes(&mut data);

            println!("Sedndg msg with data {:x?}", data);
            producer.send(
                BaseRecord::to("rt-test")
                .key(&format!("key-{}",i))
                .payload(&format!("payload-{}",i))
            )
            .expect("couldn't send message");
            // producer.flush(Duration::from_secs(1));
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(150)) // <--- Parameter to play with
        }
```

```bash
Sedndg msg with data [da, 44, 1c, f0, 6, 1d, da, 9b]
Sedndg msg with data [37, 82, b2, 58, e2, 91, 40, 33]
Sedndg msg with data [8d, f8, 5c, df, 68, 12, a1, 26]
Sedndg msg with data [bd, 13, 7c, 81, 62, 5c, 93, 75]
Produced message key-1 successfully. Offset: 193. Partition :0
Produced message key-2 successfully. Offset: 194. Partition :0
Produced message key-3 successfully. Offset: 195. Partition :0
Produced message key-4 successfully. Offset: 196. Partition :0
Sedndg msg with data [d, 9d, 1c, 73, a7, 9f, b4, 2]
Produced message key-5 successfully. Offset: 197. Partition :0
Sedndg msg with data [c9, 1a, 3b, 8c, 31, cc, 84, f4]
Produced message key-6 successfully. Offset: 198. Partition :0
Sedndg msg with data [8a, 33, 26, 92, 2a, bf, d1, 7d]
Produced message key-7 successfully. Offset: 199. Partition :0
Sedndg msg with data [78, eb, e2, 41, 8d, b9, 29, 68]
```

Comment: what are messages 8 and 9?

Comment: @user253751 same as the other ones, just 8 random bytes and ("key-{}",i) key